# iOS Swift Setting Values In a Dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsmutabledictionary

I need to access and then replace items in a dictionary.  I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do it in Swift.  I load a plist which looks something like this:

```
<dict>
<key>Brynthia</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>389</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>267</integer>
        <key>moves</key>
        <array>
            <integer>31</integer>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <integer>30</integer>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <integer>7</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>x</key>
        <integer>457</integer>
        <key>y</key>
        <integer>275</integer>
        <key>moves</key>
        <array>
            <integer>31</integer>
            <integer>6</integer>
            <integer>30</integer>
            <integer>0</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
            <integer>-1</integer>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
```

I need to modify the x and y values in each dictionary of the array.  My code I use to read them is:

```
var kings:[NSMutableDictionary] = []
        var coords:NSMutableDictionary?
        var x = 0.00
        var y = 0.00

        for var i=0;i<4;i++ {
            kings=mapDict?.objectForKey(kingdomNames[i]) as! [NSMutableDictionary]
            for var loc=0;loc<kings.count;loc++ {
                coords = kings[i]
                x=coords!.valueForKey("x")
                y=coords!.valueForKey("y")
                x=x * Double(ratioWidth)
                y=y * Double(ratioHeight)
            }
        }
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do that but it works.  So my question is how do I put the x and y values back in the dictionary?  I know how to update a value by referencing its key but I'm not sure how to do it when the dictionary I need to reference is an element in an array.

BTW, this is not a homework assignment.

Comment: As a side note: get rid of Obj-C style. Use `[String:AnyObject]` iso. `NSMutableDictionary` and `mapDict?[kingdomNames[i]]` later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `kings` is a mutatable Swift array, you can use the normal `.setValue` method on `coords` to modify `coords` and then assign it back to the proper element in the array:

```
coords.setValue(x, forKey: "x")
kings[i] = coords
```

Comment: That was certainly simple.  I was definitely trying to overcomplicate it.  Thanks!